# Using :FORM_APP_NAME Variable on PriorityERP

Tags: javascript, web-applications, priority-web-sdk

I've build a basic JS application which accesses Priority form. 
When programming inside Priority ERP, I wanna use the newly introduced variable called : ":FORM_APP_NAME" but when I check its content it is empty.
in my app login information I use

```
{"appname":"upload"}
```

and inside Priority I use this code:

```
GOTO 100 WHERE :FORM_APP_NAME <> 'upload' ;
```

I've also tried saving the content to a file,

```
SELECT :FORM_APP_NAME 
FROM DUMMY
TABS 'C:/TMP/FORMAPPNAME.TXT';
```

but it was empty as well.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The variable name inside Priority should be :WEBSDK_APP_NAME and not :FORM_APP_NAME.

Comment: I didn't find ant documentation for this , where did you get it?